# What is a pejorative phrase or word you would call an employee who has all the free time in the world?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, pejorative-language

What is a pejorative phrase or word you would call an employee who has all the free time in the world to just to be nosy in how others wear their tie or how some one should not put their hands in their pocket or discuss unimportant ideas.

I do not want to use  the word "Nosy" as it does not describe the free time effect and as is nosiness is a secondary effect. The word has to do with "free time". the best phrase would be "All-the-spare-time-in-the-world timer" but unfortunately its not a word or a phrase.

Comment: He's a VIP -- Vacation In Plant.

Answer (score 2):

a **do-nothing**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/do-nothing)

> - n person who does no work
>        Type of:
>        nonworker
>        a person who does nothing

or an adj:

> - characterized by inability or unwillingness to work toward a goal or    assume responsibility

As in:

*He is a do-nothing employee, acting as if he has all the free time in the world.*